# Augur Project compile and debug

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, dapp-development, dapps

I starting to work on blockchain and dapps, would like to help with issues in augur can anyone explain how to debug or test run the application on my local machine to know how it works? i tried to use the augur core and follow the instruction but i get held up somewhere.

https://github.com/AugurProject/augur-core

Comment: Did you try contacting Augur developers in their stack exchange https://augur.stackexchange.com/?